# JavaScript function to convert an array to an array of strings (formatted)

Tags: javascript, node.js, lodash.js

**Input**

`categories` - an array of categories

```
[
    { id: 1, title: 'Smartphones' },
    { id: 2, title: 'Laptops' }
]
```

`products` - an array of products, linked to categories

```
[
    { id: 1, title: 'iPhone X', category_id: 1, price_min: 1200, price_max: 1700 },
    { id: 2, title: 'MacBook Pro Retina 13', category_id: 2, price_min: 1500, price_max: 4500 },
    { id: 3, title: 'Samsung Galaxy S8', category_id: 1, price_min: 0, price_max: 0 }
]
```

**Output**

```
[
    "*Smartphones*\niPhone X\n ($1200 - $1700)\nSamsung Galaxy S8 (free)",
    "*Laptops*\nMacBook Pro Retina 13 ($1500 - $4500)"
]
```

**Current implementation**

```
function printPriceList (categories, products) {
    return categories.map(category => {
        const pcontent = products
            .filter(product => product.category_id === category.id)
            .map(product => {
                const samePrice = product.price_min === product.price_max
                const price = samePrice ? product.price_min : `${product.price_min} - ${product.price_max}`

                if (price === 0) {
                    return `${product.title} (free)`
                }

                return `${product.title} ($${price})`
            })
        return [`*${category.title}*`].concat(pcontent)
    }).map(cat => cat.join('\n'))
}
```

I'd like to find out a way to refactor it to be more readable, easy to understand and efficient.

What can we use?

- all the modern JS features, like a spread operator (`...smth`)
- lodash

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First impressions:

- too much nesting, too many nested returns
- inconsistent style, inconsistent naming

You already recognized the potential for refactoring. The simplest possible technique for refactoring is renaming variables:

- Your code currently uses camelCase (`printPriceList`, `samePrice`), underscores (`category_id`, `price_min`) and something else (`pcontent`). For me, it doesn't matter that much which style you chose as long as you use it consistently and as long as you use descriptive names.

Other stylistic suggestions:

- It is a habit of mine to split complex chains such as...

  ```
  const result = elements
      .filter(...)
      .map(...);
  ```

  ...into separate assignments with self-documenting names:

  ```
  const blabla = elements.filter(...);
  const result = blabla.map(...);
  ```
- I prefer to terminate statements with semicolons instead of having to think about the rules of JavaScript's automatic semicolon insertion.
- Instead of the 'print' prefix which signals some kind of active output e.g. to a stream, you could use e.g. 'format'.

The most helpful refactoring is to extract code fragments that can be grouped together into their own functions:

- Printing a product price:

  ```
  function print_product_price({price_min, price_max}) {
      if (price_max === 0) {
          return 'free';
      } else if (price_min === price_max) {
          return `$${price_min}`;
      } else {
          return `$${price_min} - $${price_max}`
      }
  }
  ```
- Printing a product:

  ```
  function print_product(product) {
      const price = print_product_price(product);
      return `${product.title} (${price})`; 
  }
  ```
- Printing a category:

  ```
  function print_category(category, products) {
      const category_products = products.filter(product => product.category_id === category.id);

      const category_rows = [
          `*${category.title}*`,
          ...category_products.map(print_product)
      ];

      return category_rows.join('\n');
  }
  ```

  Using Lodash, the above `.filter` expression could be written as `_.filter(products, { 'category_id': category.id })` - suggested by [@Gerrit0](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/142650/gerrit0).
- And finally printing the price list:

  ```
  function print_price_list(categories, products) {
      return categories.map(category => print_category(category, products));
  }
  ```

As you can see, due to extracting those functions, no secondary or deeper nesting is needed.